# CakePHP multiple fielsets using form helper

Tags: cakephp

I'm creating a form and want to use multiple fieldsets and legends, is this possible using the form helper?

My form so far -

```
echo $this->Form->create('PatientCase');
echo $this->Form->inputs(array(
    'legend'                => 'Patient Details',
...
));
echo $this->Form->end('Save Patient Case');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See API: http://api.cakephp.org/class/form-helper#method-FormHelperinput

Mainly params like: `before`, `after`, `between` or just `format`

Answer (score 1):

If you use Form::inputs(), CakePHP will automatically wrap the fields in a fieldset:

```
echo $this->Form->inputs(array(
    'legend'=>'Login',
    'User.username',
    'User.password'
));
```

Will produce:

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>Login</legend>
    <div class='input text'>...</div>
    <div class='input password'>...</div>
</fieldset>
```

if you set 'fieldset'=>false in your inputs array, cake will suppress field fieldset markup.

You can also use (as also suggested by @kical) before and after to insert the fieldset markup - this makes your code a little less intuative:

```
echo $this->Form->input('User.username', array(
    'before'=>'<fieldset><legend>Login</legend>'
));

echo $this->Form->input('User.password', array(
    'after'=>'</fieldset>'
));
```

You can also manually insert the fieldset markup (handy if you want to customise the fieldset markup or create fieldsets within fieldsets:

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>Login</legend>
    <?php 
    echo $this->Form->input('User.username');
    echo $this->Form->input('User.password');
    ?>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, using before/between/after only results in messy code and hand-crafting HTML tags. Using Form->inputs() and the legend key, will make the best use of the FormHelper